# Adding to array from loop in PHP but do not add more keys

Tags: php

I am not sure how to get the resulting array/object to look like I want, when adding the items from a loop, but trying to prevent a new key for each item.

I need final output to look looks like this, that does not have seperate numerical keys...

```
['item-1' => 'blue widget', 'item-2' => 'red widget', 'item-3' => 'white widget']
```

or this

```
Array (
  [item-1] => blue widget
  [item-2] => red widget
  [item-3] => white widget
)
```

So given the example code below:

```
$items = array('blue widget', 'red widget', 'white widget');
$final = array();
$count_items = 1;
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $item_num = 'item-'.$count_items;
  $count_items++;
  $final[] = [$item_num => $item];
}
print_r($final);
```

But this gives me an output like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [item-1] => blue widget ) 
  [1] => Array ( [item-2] => red widget ) 
  [2] => Array ( [item-3] => white widget ) 
)
```

I tried array_push as well but got same results.

Thanks

Comment: `$final[$item_num] = $item;`

Comment: Doh!! Of course... thanks

Comment: @jsherk Since [`problem looks solved`](https://3v4l.org/F02Mq) and is like a typographical mistake, you can delete it.

Comment: I posted answer below, and I think question should stay, as it is a programming related issue and it could be an issue others have as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well sometimes we have those Homer moments ... DOH!!!

Anyways, as @billyonecan pointed out, I need to do this:

```
$items = array('blue widget', 'red widget', 'white widget');
$final = array();
$count_items = 1;
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $item_num = 'item-'.$count_items;
  $count_items++;
  $final[$item_num] = $item; //FIXED THIS LINE
}
print_r($final);
```

Which will give proper output of this:

```
Array ( 
  [item-1] => blue widget 
  [item-2] => red widget 
  [item-3] => white widget 
)
```